# pybind11 bind input output parameter

Tags: python, c++11, pybind11

my C++ code

```
void test(std::string & data) {
    data += " github";
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example11, m) {
    m.def("test", [](std::reference_wrapper<std::string> w) {
test(w.get());
    });
}
```

my python code

```
import example11

def my_test():
    data = "hello"
    example11.test(data)
    print("python: {}".format(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_test()
```

what i expect is i got **hello github**, however **hello** is gotten, is there something wrong in my code, dear guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use output parameter in Python, see detailed explaination in [the official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=reference#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference). Only mutable types(`str` exclued) can be changed in-place. Even for mutable types, you still can't get modified result since the restriction of [*pybind11*](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types).

To fix your issue, return the modified value.

```cpp
std::string test(std::string & data) {
    data += " github";
    return data;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example11, m) {
    m.def("test", &test);
}
```

in Python call

```py
data = example11.test(data)
```